# Change font family in PDF-output of kableExtra

Tags: r-markdown, kableextra

I am writing a document in R markdown and changed the font to Arial, with the help of the following YAML-header:

```
---
title: ""
output:
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
fontsize: 12pt
mainfont: Arial
---
```

In my document I am using kableExtra to output a table. However, while the text in the PDF-output is indeed in Arial, the text inside my table is still displayed in the default R markdown font in the PDF-output.

Is there any way to adjust the font family in kableExtra?

Thank you for any tips!

Comment: Can you provide a full example? Without the table itself it is hard to know exactly what is going wrong. If you want to create a table as an example, just use the built-in `mtcars` dataset i.e. something like `knitr::kable(mtcars)`.